# Failed when initializing the StAX parsing engine

Tags: servlets, jena, semantic-web, dbpedia, endpoints

im new on semantic web. Im trying to do a simple webapp which uses information from dbpedia sparql to show information from a determinated location.

Thats my code:

```
String adicional = "NO_INFO_DBPEDIA_DATA";
    if(propiedad.equals("http://dbpedia.org/ontology/location")){
        municipio = propiedadObtenida.substring(8, propiedadObtenida.length()-3);
        Query query_municipio = QueryFactory
                .create("select ?z  where {<"
                        + "http://dbpedia.org/resource/" + municipio 
                        + "> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract> ?z.FILTER (LANG(?z)='es')}");
        QueryExecution query_exec_municipio = QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(
                DBPEDIA_ENDPOINT, query_municipio);
        ResultSet results_municipio = query_exec_municipio.execSelect();

        System.out.println(query_municipio.toString());

        while (results_municipio.hasNext())
            adicional = results_municipio.next().toString();

    }
```

I check that the property im looking for is a location and then i make a query to the dbpedia endpoint sparql (http://dbpedia.org/sparql). But the program fail when executes the ResulSet showing the next error:

```
GRAVE: Servlet.service() para servlet QueryServlet lanzó excepción
com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.ResultSetException: Failed when initializing the StAX parsing engine
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInputStAX.<init>(XMLInputStAX.java:110)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInput.make(XMLInput.java:73)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInput.fromXML(XMLInput.java:42)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInput.fromXML(XMLInput.java:37)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFactory.fromXML(ResultSetFactory.java:311)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.engine.http.QueryEngineHTTP.execSelect(QueryEngineHTTP.java:371)
at org.ws1415.euskadi.restaurantes.servlet.QueryServlet.doGet(QueryServlet.java:89)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XML11NSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInputStAX$ResultSetStAX.processHead(XMLInputStAX.java:365)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInputStAX$ResultSetStAX.init(XMLInputStAX.java:183)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInputStAX$ResultSetStAX.<init>(XMLInputStAX.java:175)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInputStAX.worker(XMLInputStAX.java:135)
at com.hp.hpl.jena.sparql.resultset.XMLInputStAX.<init>(XMLInputStAX.java:106)
... 28 more
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: This appears to relate to a recent change at DBPedia to use XML 1.1 which the Xerces library that Jena uses for parsing XML data does not handle properly - see [JENA-940](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-940)

Comment: It is a [Java OpenJDK/Oracle JDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029437).  To add to the comment of @RobV [JENA-942](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JENA-942) collects possible ways to workaround this.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the Jena mailing list, I found this quick workaround:

```
    QueryEngineHTTP qexec = (QueryEngineHTTP) QueryExecutionFactory.sparqlService(uri, query);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        qexec.setSelectContentType(WebContent.contentTypeResultsJSON);
        ResultSet results = qexec.execSelect();
        return results;
    } finally {

    }
```

Instead of using the QueryExecution class, I used the QueryEngineHTTP class and set a different content type (JSON in this case).

I hope this helps.

Comment: If you can modify the application code, a simpler way is to switch to SAX parsing: `SystemARQ.UseSAX = true ;`